# Grammar for speaking in the future

Tags: grammar, future

I am going to meet with someone in the future to discuss something. In an email I sent to this person, I wanted to tell him what I wanted to talk about. In my head

"I **was** hoping to talk to you about..."

sounded right, but "was" is past tense, so I was confused whether this was correct or not. I changed it to:

"I **am** hoping to talk to you about..."

What is the correct way to say this?

Comment: Hello @kneedhelp, Welcome to English Language & Usage. ELU prefers questions which demonstrate some research effort on the part of the questioner. Please cite any sources you've explored thus far in trying to answer this question. _Thanks!_

Comment: We use past tense forms for many things besides talking about the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb 'hope' itself has a future reference in its meanings.

"I hope/am hoping to talk to...both forms are possible. Or, if a more polite request form is required, "I was hoping to talk to...." is better.

To talk about unrealised hopes, 'had hoped' (past perfect form) can be used.

Definition of **hope** from **Merriam-Webster**:

```
*intransitive verb*

1    :  to cherish a desire with anticipation :  to want something to happen or be true. 


*transitive verb*

1    :  to desire with expectation of obtainment or fulfillment.

2    :  to expect with confidence.
```

**Hope**
from **English Grammar Today** (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/hope)

Hope is a verb and a noun.

**Hope as a verb**

After hope, we often use present verb forms even when there is reference to the future:

```
We hope she passes her driving test next week.

I just hope the bus is on time tomorrow.
```

Warning:

We don’t normally use hope in the negative:

```
I hope it doesn’t rain.

Not: I don’t hope it rains.
```

The past continuous of hope is used to make polite statements and, especially, polite requests:

```
I was hoping to have a word with you, Professor O’Malley.

We were hoping you could lend us your car while you were in America.
```

Comment: Additionally, "I am hoping to talk to you about ..." can be used in a more formal context, probably emphasising a greater degree of  uncertainty about this occurring. / Stressed "I **was**  hoping to talk to you about ..." indicates that the possibility has largely vanished, with the addressee quite possibly being at fault.